# Long-distance fluid handling with pipes

Tags: factorio

I have difficulty to fill my steam engine. There is a very long distance between the water source and my base. Actually, the half of my steam engine network fill up well, but the other half doesn't.

I tried to :

- Add small pumps near the offshore pumps
- Add small pumps near the boilers
- Add small pumps at both places
- Add small pumps near the boilers

Nothing works. When I put the same number boilers/steam engines near the offshore pumps, it works well, but when I put them in my base, it doesn't.

I know there is [liquids and pipes physics](https://wiki.factorio.com/index.php?title=Liquids/Pipe_physics). I've read the articles on the official wiki, but there is probably something I didn't see about long-distance fluid handling with pipes (and small pumps).

**Does someone have a solution to this problem, or a part of the solution ?** or something to try that I didn't do ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A single pipe can only carry so much water, regardless of how many pumps are connected to it.

The optimal setup is:

- 1 pump
- Any number of pipes
- 14 boilers
- 10 steam engines

Any more boilers/engines will be wasted due to lack of water.  To generate more electricity, use another pump to supply a separate series of pipes.

Comment: Does this still hold for .15? A lot of the mechanics of steam power were changed.

Comment: In .16 its 1 pump, 20 boilers and 40 steam engines

Answer (score 7):

Instead of taking water to your base with pipes, why not just put the steam engines next to the water supply, then take the electricity to your base with power lines or pylons? You can always protect the steam engines with walls, gates and turrets.